# Why is my barplot graph showing up stacked, instead of grouped?

Tags: r, grouped-bar-chart

I don't know why my graph is showing up stacking the data, instead of grouping it.

```
rawdat <- c(4.2, 4.6, 4.1, 3.9, 5.0, 3.9)
m <- matrix(rawdat, nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = F)
rownames(m) <- c(0,1)
colnames(m) <- c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3")
barplot(m)
```